# Ideal of matrix ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, ideals

I'm going over some exercises and I'm not quite sure if I completely understand this one.

> Let $R=M_3(\mathbb{Q})$, i.e. $R$ is the ring of all $3\times3$ matrices over rational numbers. Describe the minimal right ideal of $R$ containing the matrix
>   $$\begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & 0 & 1 \\
> 1 & 1 & 0 \\
> 0 & 1 & 1 \\
> \end{bmatrix}$$

M̶y̶ ̶g̶u̶e̶s̶s̶ ̶w̶a̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶I̶'̶m̶ ̶j̶u̶s̶t̶ ̶s̶u̶p̶p̶o̶s̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶f̶i̶n̶d̶ ̶a̶ ̶m̶a̶t̶r̶i̶x̶ ̶i̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶f̶i̶t̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶d̶e̶f̶i̶n̶i̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶a̶ ̶r̶i̶g̶h̶t̶ ̶i̶d̶e̶a̶l̶,̶ ̶w̶h̶i̶c̶h̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶∀̶ ̶r̶ ̶∈̶ ̶R̶:̶ ̶i̶ ̶·̶ ̶r̶ ̶∈̶ ̶I̶ ̶(̶r̶ ̶b̶e̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶g̶i̶v̶e̶n̶ ̶m̶a̶t̶r̶i̶x̶)̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶I̶ ̶=̶ ̶{̶(̶i̶)̶}̶ ̶.̶

But the more I tried to find something similar to this problem, the more I think that this is absolutely wrong. Can somebody help me with this and maybe explain how to get to the solution?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

My previous idea was a mix up of definitions, from the comments I now understand that I need to find $I$ (which contains the given matrix), but I'm still confused as to how to do so.

Comment: Ideals are not matrices! Ideals are sets of matrices. You need to find the smallest $I \subseteq R$ such that $\left(\array{1&0&1\\1&1&0\\0&1&1}\right)\in I$ and for any $r \in R$ and any $i \in I$, $ir \in I$.

Comment: I second what @user3482749 said. It seems that you don't quite understand the definition of ideals, so you need to go back and read it more carefully. What you stated as a "definition" has bits and pieces of the correct one, but the way it's stated doesn't make much sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimal right ideal of $R$ containing $r\in R$ is $rR=\{rs:s\in R\}$. In your case it is the set of *all* products of the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where the second matrix varies through all elements of $R=M_{3}(\mathbb{Q})$.

Can this be described more easily, at least in this case? Well, the given matrix is…

Comment: that's it? just the product of those two matrices? I should've known it wasn't anything too complicated, thank you very much

Comment: @Alex No, you didn't read carefully or I didn't explain myself too well: it is the set of *all* matrices of that form, infinitely many of them. But in this particular case, a property of the fixed matrix can be used.

Comment: no, sorry I have no idea where you're going with this

Comment: @Alex Call $r$ the given matrix. Then $r^{-1}$ exists and belongs to $R$, so among the elements of $rR$ there is $rr^{-1}=1$.

Comment: okay so the ideal will contain identity??

Comment: @Alex And therefore…

Comment: so that means $I$ = $R$

Comment: @Alex Indeed. That’s it.

Comment: thank you, I just have one question how do I determine the ideal when I'm given a singular matrix?

Comment: @Alex In that case you get a linear system that you need to solve.